# Populating DropDownList on the basis of selection in another DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ok, so this is what i am wanting to do. I have 2 `DropDownLists`. One is `DataBound`. One is `Deprtmnt`, other one is `Doctor`. What i want to do is, when i select a `Department` e.g *Cardiology* from the DropDownList `Deprtmnt`,the other `DropDownList` should get populated with the `Doctors` belonging to the *Cardiology Department* only.
When i click on the department cardiology, the doctors' names don't show in the other dropdownlist 
This is what i have done so far. 
Apsx code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Deprtmnt" runat="server" Height="32px" Width="227px">
                             <asp:ListItem>(None)</asp:ListItem>
                             <asp:ListItem>Opthalomology</asp:ListItem>
                             <asp:ListItem>Dermatology</asp:ListItem>
                             <asp:ListItem>Cardiology</asp:ListItem>
                             <asp:ListItem>Neurology</asp:ListItem>
                             </asp:DropDownList>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="32px" Width="229px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Sname" DataValueField="Sname">
                             </asp:DropDownList>
                             <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SMCConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT Sname FROM StaffRec WHERE (Designation = N'Doctor' AND Department = N'Deprtmnt.SelectedItem.Text')"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

c# code:

```
string str = "INSERT INTO Appointments(Apname,Department,Doctor,Date) values (@Apname,@Department,@Doctor,@Date)";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Apname", name.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", Deprtmnt.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Doctor", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", TextBox1.Text);
        con.Open();
```

Rest of the code is not related so i am not posting it. 
Any Kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When i click on the `department cardiology`, the doctors' names don't show in the other `dropdownlist`

Comment: @SanaQureshi: Does any data exist for `doctors`?

Comment: Also, why are you using `SelectedItem.Text` instead of use `SelectedValue`

Comment: Try setting `AutoPostBack = true` for the first Dropdownlist

Comment: @NadeemKhan, yes i have a doctor added under `Cardiology`. So besically, when i select `cardiology`, it should display his `name` in 2nd `dropdownlist`. I tried setting the `AutoPostBack = true` for first `DropDownList`, it didn't help. and How may i use the `SelectedValue`?

Comment: @NadeemKhan, ok tried `SelectedValue` as well, no use still

Comment: @SanaQureshi: Do you have added `onSelectedIndexChanged` property added for the first dropdownlist ?? IT will check and on that basis it will show the data. Also, on second note, do you have added the relation properly in the Database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72972/discussion-between-nadeem-khan-and-sana-qureshi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `AutoPostBack=true`
You need to use `ControlParameter` in `SelectParameters`.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Deprtmnt" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Height="32px" Width="227px">
                             <asp:ListItem>(None)</asp:ListItem>
                             <asp:ListItem>Opthalomology</asp:ListItem>
                             <asp:ListItem>Dermatology</asp:ListItem>
                             <asp:ListItem>Cardiology</asp:ListItem>
                             <asp:ListItem>Neurology</asp:ListItem>
                             </asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="32px" Width="229px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Sname" DataValueField="Sname">
     </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SMCConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT Sname FROM StaffRec WHERE (Designation = N'Doctor' AND Department = @department)">
    <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Deprtmnt" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                Name="Department" Type="String" DefaultValue="Opthalomology" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: I am not getting any error. It's just not populating the 2nd dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

@SanaQureshi: why don't you do it with a $.ajax method call and create a webmethod in your C# code. I believe its the best way to fill dropdowns dynamically.

Comment: i am afraid i am new to aspx and c#. So no idea what you are talkin about. Can you guide me some more please?

Comment: Please see this if it may help you...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23572800/populate-item-to-dropdown-by-using-ajax-call-and-assign-selected-value